# How to Transfer Data From Oracle database to DB2 Using Java

Tags: java, oracle, db2

In our project on daily basis, We have to transfer all the data from the Oracle database to DB2 database. Oracle database has three schemas and multiple tables inside one schema.

We have to develop this data transfer utility using the Java program.

Could anyone please help me, what should be my approach.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you thought of anything? Post some code of what you've done si far so we can see at what stage are you stuck.

Comment: @zuckermanori: sure, I will edit my post and add here my code also. Thanks

Comment: Approach: select all rows in Oracle, for rows in resultset, insert row into DB2.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using Federation to pull the data to Db2 using SQL.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/FedServer_product_landing.html

If you are using Db2 11 (for LUW), heterogeneous federation (i.e. "Federation with all other data sources, including Oracle") is included in the Advanced Db2 editions.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.licensing.doc/doc/r0053238.html

The supported federated sources are listed here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27049211